# Why Does this SQL query work, but the other doesn't?

Tags: sql

I am learning SQL, and in **[this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_max)** I can write this:

```
SELECT MAX(Price) AS Price, ProductName
FROM Products;
```

Which returns what I expect:

```
Price   ProductName
263.5   Côte de Blaye
```

But on **[StrataScratch](https://platform.stratascratch.com/coding-question?id=10308&python=)** when I am trying to begin to solve a problem (I am currently just seeing what ideas will work towards a solution) this (and similar variations) throws an error

```
SELECT MAX(salary) AS salary, first_name
FROM db_employee;
```

error:

```
(psycopg2.errors.GroupingError) column "db_employee.first_name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT MAX(salary) AS salary, first_name
```

Conceptually these seem like the same query to me, so I am not sure why the query from StrataScratch throws an error.

Comment: The first one is invalid standard SQL and will be rejected by any self-respecting database. It seems that w3fools is using a database that does not care about the SQL standard or consistent results

Answer (score 1):

It's literally telling you why right there. `MAX()` is an aggregate function. Aggregate functions need a `GROUP BY` statement if the query is going to include a standard column.

```
SELECT MAX(Price) as Price, ProductName
FROM Products
GROUP BY ProductName
```

It fails because SQL won't know automatically that it should establish a relationship between the max price and product name. Remember SQL is a RELATIONAL database language. All of the data must be somehow related. SQL is not going to guess, you need to explicitly establish a relationship between `Price` and `ProductName`

I really recommend you to read some articles about SQL debugging. I've noticed that a lot of new students have subpar debugging skills and SQL debugging messages are actually incredibly informative.

Comment: ```SELECT MAX(Price) as Price, ProductName
FROM Products``` is actually working on W3 without the GROUP BY

Comment: No it's not, go run that code on the link you provided

"You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'ProductName' as part of an aggregate function."

The link you wrote has the query `SELECT MAX(Price) AS LargestPrice
FROM Products;`

This is completely valid SQL because it's just 1 column. If you add one more non-aggregate-function-column, you're going to get an error.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. I understand the need for grouping, but the fact it "worked" on W3 was confusing me and making me doubt. Thanks.

Comment: The code is not working in W3, I just tried it. You most likely got confused.

Comment: Strange, **[here's](https://imgur.com/a/NbmtLNn)** what I'm seeing

Comment: I believe you must be seeing a residual (cached) result from a previous query. Your results have only 1 row, whereas if you add a group by statement, you're going to get over 20.

It's indeed strange behavior but you can just attribute it to their editor using a weird SQL flavor. It's not something you're going to encounter in production systems.

Comment: Okay, cool, I'll disregard. What ended up working in Strata was ```SELECT salary, first_name
FROM db_employee
WHERE salary = ( SELECT MAX(salary) FROM db_employee)``` which seems nice and clean to me.

Comment: You should really just use a group by and order by the amount, and if you're decided in getting just 1 result, then just at a `LIMIT 1` at the end (or whichever syntax your RDBMS uses to limit results). Your query is just not scalable. Imagine if your table had a million records, you'd be running an operation to determine the max salary, then you'd be running another one to pull all the salaries of the first table, then another one to see if the results match. 

`Select max(salary), productname from product group by productname order by max(salary) desc limit 1` is much cleaner.

Comment: Oh awesome! Makes total sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a group by clause here, like this:

```
SELECT MAX(Price) AS Price, ProductName
FROM Products
GROUP BY ProductName
```

Comment: At least on W3 I don't need one, which is confusing me. When I add GROUP BY first_name on Strata I get a table of all of the salaries and first_names

Comment: I have no idea why the first one works for your data set. Maybe it's a Strata thing? For normal SQL I think it's just an error.

Comment: You definitely need to use a GROUP BY. You have an aggregate and a column name being used in your SELECT clause. @a_horse_with_no_name with the comment above is right. I don't know what w3school's is doing but their query wouldn't work on most dbs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the product with the maximum price, then use `order by` and limit the results to one row.  In standard SQL this is:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Products p
ORDER BY p.price DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

(The last line of code is often `LIMIT 1`.)

Your first query:

```
SELECT MAX(Price) AS Price, ProductName
FROM Products;
```

should fail with a syntax error -- and would in almost all databases.  Why?  Because this is an aggregation query (because of the `MAX()` but `ProductName` is not aggregated and not part of a `GROUP BY`).

It does work in (at least) two databases.  In older versions of MySQL, you would get an *arbitrary* `ProductName`.  By luck, you might get the right one, but that would be a coincidence.  MySQL has since fixed this so the query should return an error in more recent versions (using default configuration settings).

SQLite does permit such syntax and actually returns the `ProductName` associated with the maximum price.  However, I don't recommend learning that as "valid" SQL, because it only works in SQLite.